# Apache Airflow + Python 3.6 + Local Executor + Mysql as a metadata database

Tags: python-3.6, mysql-python, airflow

Airflow version 1.8
Python version 3.6
i am getting No module named 'MySQLdb' error
when i configure the Airflow with LocalExecutor and Mysql as metadata database.
i am not able to install the MySQLdb package due to version issue.

anyone having idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks
Kalanidhi

Comment: I think this is more question for SuperUser.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your version issue?

Comment: after configuring airflow.cfg like 
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+pymysql://airflowuser:mysql@localhost:3306/airflowdb its started working. Actually here i am using pymysql package instead of MySQLdb package(@joeb: - it seems MySQLdb package not supporting python 3+ version)

Answer (score 0):

after configuring airflow.cfg like sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+pymysql://airflowuser:mysql@localhost:3306/airflowdb its started working. Actually here i am using pymysql package instead of MySQLdb package(@joeb: - it seems MySQLdb package not supporting python 3+ version)